# Is there any mention in Hindu mythology of time slowing down or stopping for people who are doing severe penance?

Tags: identification-request, time

In Hindu mythology, there are several tales of sages, warriors, etc performing penance for months, hundreds and even thousands of years.

For example, **Amba, Arjuna, Jayadrath, Ravana, Vishwamitra,** etc. in various mythological stories.

Is there any mention of time slowing down or stopping for such people in the tales or other texts, so that the timelines with other relevant characters are still matching?

Comment: In the stories of Amba, Arjuna, Jayadrath, Ravana, Vishwamitra, etc., it was not mentioned that while they are doing austerities, their age was stalled.  Mention of performing penance for months, hundreds and even thousands of years, etc, is only allegorical, indicating severe austerities can result in powers.  Their purpose is not beyond that.

Comment: It seems weird though there is no mention of this, as there would have been a difference in ages of different characters messing up the chronological order of events.

Comment: Well scriptures say that in earlier yugas people lived for thousand of years - penance or no penance. So should not be surprising

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are mentions of Time slowing down or stopping for Siddhars and Sages. Some of the Thirumoolar Thirumanthiram and Nava Nadha Siddhar books in Tamil talk about that. The state of Paraparam onwards is Pure timelessness. There are several different timelines below each going at varying speed. So get out of yours and come back a thousand years could be past, depending on the speed of your imposed timeline on soul's forced extraction - or voluntary extrication( moksha) :-)! One of the recent Kundalini books ["Kundalini: an Untold Story..."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0994002793) by Om Swami(...mmmm)
 also quotes some references to a scripture story where in a brother Mahasena of a king Sushena - actually in ["The vision of the Hill City - Tripura Rahasya"](https://www.thedaobums.com/topic/47777-brahma-rishis-the-mystic-masters-who-created-their-own-universes/) - who is led outside of his time line and more than 10,000 years have elapsed since his return.
So, Time is relative - even in Hinduism and concurs with science :-). When you say thousands of years, you also have to refer to the time line. It makes no sense to say just 
 the count of years without specifying the rate, linearity and other time functions...Like External Brahma's is zillions of years slower. You can refer to Kalpa, etc. When your soul transitions to speedier or slower timelines( Is this a Quantum "Soul particle" Jump on Eigenstates...mmmmm...) so does your experience vary. SO, when you are in timeless state you can manifest your soul onto any point of any timeline and interfere with the workings. The Souls committed to that timelines ( who are like Jivanmuktas ) could do that as well..
Kalagni Rudra can burn timelines back to their elemental consciousness when necessary...
I'll leave it at that...

Comment: Please provide references.

Comment: Tripura Rahasya source, refer to King Sushena’s brother Mahasena’s  adventure ...Here: https://www.thedaobums.com/topic/47777-brahma-rishis-the-mystic-masters-who-created-their-own-universes/